# Entity Framework Version - 4.1.10715 has targetFramework of "net35" but depends on mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: entity-framework

I have tried EF 4.1.10715 and EF 4.1.10331.0 both packages seem to target Framework 3.5, but have dependencies on mscorlib, Version 4.0.0.0

Below is screenshot of Package Config for Version 4.1.10331.0 from this morning.

[image: ScreenShot from Package Config]

At compilation, we fail with

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "EntityFramework" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After created a new WinForm project in Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 3.5 as the target framework, I installed the 4.1.10715.0 version of Entity Framework and had the same issues.

Opening the referenced EntityFramework assembly in dotPeek confirms that it was compiled for .NET 4.0.

Despite the targetFramework indicated 3.5 in packages.config, the referenced assembly has been compiled for .NET 4.0.

`<packages>
<package id="EntityFramework" version="4.1.10715.0" targetFramework="net35" /></packages>`

Looks like someone mishandled a package prior to publishing.

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramework 4.0+ (including 4.1) do not support .NET Framework 3.5. The only version you can use on a .NET Framework 3.5 is EF1 which is part of the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. So, if you don't have the SP1 version you won't be able to use EF at all.

Comment: Pawel:  All correct statements.  The problem is the packages.config for version 4.1.10715.0 shows a targetFramework of 'net35'.  This is really the issue I am trying to understand.  Think it is a simple error and wanted to use Stack Overflow to call into attention.

Comment: @DylanPhillips - but what is your project's target .NET Framework version? I think you see "net35" because your project is targeting .NET Framework 3.5. I don't think the EF NuGet package checks anything about the project your installing it into - it has just one `lib` folder which I believe means install it into whatever project the user wants it to install.